# Simplifying loop with Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I have a method that adds maps to a cache and I was wondering what I could do more to simplify this loop with Java 8.

What I have done so far: 
Standard looping we all know:

```
for(int i = 0; i < catalogNames.size(); i++){
    List<GenericCatalog> list = DummyData.getCatalog(catalogNames.get(i));
    Map<String, GenericCatalog> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(GenericCatalog item : list){
        map.put(item.name.get(), item);
    }
    catalogCache.put(catalogNames.get(i), map);};
```

Second iteration using forEach:

```
catalogNames.forEach(e -> {
    Map<String, GenericCatalog> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    DummyData.getCatalog(e).forEach(d -> {
        map.put(d.name.get(), d);
    });
    catalogCache.put(e, map);});
```

And third iteration that removes unnecessary bracers:

```
catalogNames.forEach(objName -> {
    Map<String, GenericCatalog> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    DummyData.getCatalog(objName).forEach(obj -> map.put(obj.name.get(), obj));
    catalogCache.put(objName, map);});
```

My question now is what can be further done to simplify this? 
I do understand that it's not really necessary to do anything else with this method at this point, but, I was curios about the possibilities.

Comment: Tip: shorter does not always mean simpler

Comment: Why do you want to simplify this. I think your solution #2 is conceive and you understand directly what it does.

Comment: As I said in the question, I agree that solution #2 and solution #3 are both easy and simple (I'm using #2 in the code atm). I was just curious about what more can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is small issue with solution 2 and 3 they might cause a [side effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in
>   general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations
>   of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety
>   hazards.
>
> As an example of how to transform a stream pipeline that
>   inappropriately uses side-effects to one that does not, the following
>   code searches a stream of strings for those matching a given regular
>   expression, and puts the matches in a list.

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
 stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
       .forEach(s -> results.add(s));  // Unnecessary use of side-effects!
```

So instead of using `forEach` to populate the `HashMap` it is better to use `Collectors.toMap(..)`. I am not 100% sure about your data structure, but I hope it is close enough.

There is a `List` and corresponding `Map`:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

Map<Integer,List<Double>> catalog = new HashMap<>();
catalog.put(1,Arrays.asList(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4));
catalog.put(2,Arrays.asList(1.1,2.2,3.3));
catalog.put(3,Arrays.asList(1.1,2.2));
```

now we would like to get a new `Map` where a map `key` is element from the original `List` and `map value` is an other `Map` itself. The nested `Map's`  key is transformed element from `catalog` `List` and `value` is the `List` element itself. Crazy description and more crazy code below:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> result = ints.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
                el -> el, 
                el -> catalog.get(el).stream().
                        collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                c -> c.intValue(), 
                                c -> c
                        ))

        )
);
System.out.println(result);
// {1={1=1.1, 2=2.2, 3=3.3, 4=4.4}, 2={1=1.1, 2=2.2, 3=3.3}, 3={1=1.1, 2=2.2}}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about utilizing Collectors from the stream API? Specifically, `Collectors#toMap`

```
Map<String, Map<String, GenericCatalog>> cache = catalogNames.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
    name -> DummyData.getCatalog(name).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.name.get(), Function.identity(),
            //these two lines only needed if HashMap can't be used
            (o, t) -> /* merge function */,
            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

This avoids mutating an existing collection, and provides you your own individual copy of a map (which you can use to update a cache, or whatever you desire).

Also I would disagree with arbitrarily putting end braces at the end of a line of code - most style guides would also be against this as it somewhat disturbs the flow of the code to most readers.